# React-native Draggable Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to achieve this kind of feature

[image: A component hidden inside until the item is dragged]

The box on top of this image is supposed to be a draggable component from the top to the bottom till the component is full visible, it is also suppose to be animated. I am trying to make a feature like this with `react-native-draggable` library so in my code I am using a small box to try it but all to no avail.

This is my code:

```
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native"
import { StatusBar } from "react-native"
import { Text } from "react-native"
import { Component } from "react"
import { View } from "react-native"
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import { Dimensions } from "react-native"
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Animated } from "react-native"
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons"
import { ScrollView } from "react-native"
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"
import Draggable from "react-native-draggable"
import { useState } from "react"

function FocusAwareStatusBar(props) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return isFocused ? <StatusBar {...props} /> : null;
}

const Trading = () => {
  const [yPosition, setYPosition] = useState(10);
  const [animatedValue, setAnimatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const onDragRelease = (e, gestureState) => {
    if (gestureState.moveY > 100) {
      Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start(() => {
        setYPosition(10);
      });
    } else {
      Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 200,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start(() => {
        setYPosition(10);
      });
    }
  };

  const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: animatedValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, Dimensions.get("window").height / 2 - 70],
        }),
      },
    ],
  };

 return(
  <>
    <FocusAwareStatusBar barStyle={"light-content"} backgroundColor="#360061" translucent={false}/>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.draggableContainer, animatedStyle]}>
      <Draggable
        x={100}
        y={yPosition}
        onDragRelease={onDragRelease}
      >
        <View style={{width: 150, height: 150, backgroundColor: 'purple'}} />
      </Draggable>
    </Animated.View>
  </>
 )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  draggableContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: Dimensions.get("window").height / 2 - 75,
    left: Dimensions.get("window").width / 2 - 75,
    zIndex: 1,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 2 + 75,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Trading;
```

I discovered in my cold that the box still drags to left and right, I don't want that, I have tried `react-native-interactable` but it's not working.